# How can I load all entities of a given kind from Cloud Datastore with Objectify?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have about a hundred objects stored in the Cloud Datastore with `Kind` = `Animal`. I would like to get all `Animal`s from the database via the low level API or with Objectify.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Objectify you can do the following:

```
List<Animal> animals = ofy().load().type(Animal.class).list();
```

Read the documentation on [queries](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Queries) it explains in detail how to query the `Datastore` using Objectify. In some ways I find the Objectify documentation to be much simpler to understand and concise compared to the GAE documentation.